# Matching a string to an array

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, match

I need your your help,

For some strange reason, when my `var str` is set to "`OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA`" the matched key comes back as "`ASF`" as opposed to "`ASFA`"

How can I get the returned output key of "`ASFA`" when my str is "`OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA`"

```
function test() {

    var str = "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA"

    var filenames = {
        "OTHER-REQUEST-ASF": "ASF",
        "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA": "ASFA",
        "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB": "ASFB",
        "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC": "ASFC",
        "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFE": "ASFE" 
    }

    for (var key in filenames) {
        if (str.indexOf(key) != -1) { alert(filenames[key]) }
    }

}
```

Comment: If you want the entry in `filenames` that goes with the key, it's just `filenames[key]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could switch from

```
str.indexOf(key)
```

to

```
key.indexOf(str)
```

```js
function test() {
    var str = "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA",
        filenames = {
            "OTHER-REQUEST-ASF": "ASF",
            "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA": "ASFA",
            "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB": "ASFB",
            "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC": "ASFC",
            "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFE": "ASFE" 
        },
        key;

    for (key in filenames) {
        if (key.indexOf(str) != -1) {
            console.log(filenames[key]);
        }
    }
}

test();
```

Answer (score 1):

To answer why it's not working as you want...

You've got:

```
str.indexOf(key)
```

This checks for the first instance of `key` in `str`.

So in your loop, `key` first equals `OTHER-REQUEST-ASF` which is part of `OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA`, so the condition is true.

---

However, to do what you *want* to do, if you know the pattern is always going to be `OTHER-REQUEST-XYZ`, the easiest way is to use [`split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split):

```
str.split('-')[2]
```

will always return the last section after the last `-`

Answer (score 0):

cause "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA".indexOf("OTHER-REQUEST-ASF") will not return -1, so it will show "ASF"

Answer (score 0):

You can also use static method Object.keys() to abtain array of keys

```js
var test = () =>{
  var str = "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA"

  var filenames = {
    "OTHER-REQUEST-ASF": "ASF",
    "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFA": "ASFA",
    "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFB": "ASFB",
    "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFC": "ASFC",
    "OTHER-REQUEST-ASFE": "ASFE"
  }
  Object.keys(filenames).forEach(x => {
    if ( x.indexOf(str) !== -1) 
      console.log(filenames[str]);
  });
}
test();
```